# Kill all Screen Sessions with Same Name

Tags: linux, gnu-screen, kill, gnu

I have multiple screen sessions with the same name due to a bug. How can I remove these all in 1 command without affecting other screen sessions?

I used the command from this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509677/kill-detached-screen-session

However it only prints out the sessions and doesn't remove them:

What can I do to remove these sessions in 1 go without affecting other sessions?

Thank you

Comment: Is the answer/Comments here what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14447131/kill-all-detached-screen-sessions

Comment: Oo that is very similar. Is there a modified version to kill via the screen nam rather than the Pid? Because the Pid is different every time. That looks like it would remove all?

Comment: Are they always detached?

Comment: Yes they are always detached

Comment: Have you tried this `screen -ls | grep Detached | cut -d. -f1 | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill`

Comment: That is still based on pid. How can it be changed to accomodate the screen name instead? I.e. thrasher_****************? Really appreciate your help so far thank you

Comment: Going to have to look into this a bit. Will let you know if I stumble upon anything or figure it out.

Comment: @NetworkKingPin's solution is based on PID, all right, but it takes *current* PID as of when command is executed. Thus *“Because the Pid is different every time.”* should not be an issue … or?

Comment: Well there are many more sessions than the one shown in my screenshot. I'm only selecting the ones based on the name given. If I use that command then I believe it will cancel all other sessions as well. I purely want to kill sessions with that specific name ignoring the pid as that will affect others. I hope I'm being clear enough. @NetworkKingPin - Thank you!!

Comment: @NetworkKingPin Did you manage to find a solution mate? Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Here is what i used to kill all the screens named my_screens_to_kill_named_the_same:

```bash
# Checking if there are some screen named 
if screen -list | grep -q "my_screens_to_kill_named_the_same"; then
    # Get the list of id of screens named
    ids_to_kill="$(screen -ls | awk '/\.my_screens_to_kill_named_the_same\t/' | awk '{print strtonum($1)}')"
    # Loop on that list and kill all the screens named
    for id_to_kill in ${ids_to_kill}
    do  
        screen -X -S "$id_to_kill" quit
    done
fi
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).